# Whats is MongoDB version of mysql DISTINCT

Tags: mongodb

How can I run this command using mongodb?

SELECT DISTINCT  `data1` ,  `data2` 
FROM table
WHERE  `data3` =  'example'

Comment: Did you do *any* research before posting this? I mean... `"mongo distinct"` - two word search and the answer is the first result... [so] is not an alternative for google (even if we are usually the first hit :P )

Comment: If you're using Mongo, your data wouldn't be organized in the same manner as it would a normalized SQL database.  This question wouldn't really have a real "apples to apples" translation because it wouldn't exist.  There ARE times when you'd need to get distinct entities from Mongo, in which case there is the distinct funtion Pierre mentions in his answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I see that the title here is misleading. Im aware that mongodb has distinct and was playing around with it before submitting this post. My problem is that it only supports 1 field, so does not give the same desired result. 

So clarify my question what is the best work around to achieve the same result as above?

Comment: Use the aggregation framework like so: `db.col.aggregate([{$match:{data3:'example'}},{$group:{_id:{a:'$data1',b:'$data2'}}}])` Which was supposed to be the right answer but everyone put the wrong answer...I tried to tell them

Comment: lack of trying before asking..

Answer (score 3):

What about [mongodb distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) function. Please refer to [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) for more details also.

As Brian Vanderbusch said in its comment above, you'll most likely endup with a complete different data structure when using SQL and NoSQL databases.

Also thanks to Sammaye comments, the mongodb distinct function does not support 2 keys. You would have to use the aggregation framework:

```
db.col.aggregate([{$match:{data3:'example'}},{$group:{_id:{a:'$data1',b:'$data2‌​'}}}])
```

Comment: I really don't feel that this question warrants an answer... It's the first google hit for `"mongo distinct"`.. This might have been better as a comment.

Comment: actually distinct is not equal to the abbove sql

Comment: No it won't, he is looking for some of complete opposite, the aggregation framework.

Comment: It won't return the value he is looking for, it can't

Comment: read the SQL again, you will realise this won't work

Comment: Hmm Brian has a good point but it wasn't the one I was making, he wants to return a compound distinct, whereas distinct in MongoDB cannot do that